# How to find element using classname starting with the text in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Below is the element description:

```
<div class="css-control-textinput-122aa"><input type="text" aria-required="true" disabled="" required=""</div>
```

In the above class is having name `css-control-textinput-122aa`, but here `122aa` is not fixed value, it gets changed. So how do I find the element using `className` starting with `css-control-textinput` only?

Below the code I tried, but it's not working:

```
@FindBy (className = "css-fauxcontrol-textinput-^")
List<WebElement> dataSourceName;
```

Answer (score 14):

`className` needs full class. For partial class name you can use `cssSelector`

```
@FindBy (css = "[class^='css-fauxcontrol-textinput-']")
List<WebElement> dataSourceName;
```

Or `xpath`

```
@FindBy (xpath = "//div[starts-with(@class, 'css-control-textinput-')]")
List<WebElement> dataSourceName;
```

Answer (score 4):

Possibly there is an issue with the HTML you have shared. The `<input>` tag should have been closed by a `>` and the actual *HTML* must have been:

```
<div class="css-control-textinput-122aa"><input type="text" aria-required="true" disabled="" required=""></div>
```

In this cases, simply identifying the `<div>` may not help us but we need to traverse till the child `<input>` node and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css`:

  ```
  @FindBy (css  = "div[class^='css-control-textinput-']>input[type='text']")
  List<WebElement> dataSourceName;
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  @FindBy (xpath  = "//div[starts-with(@class,'css-control-textinput-')]/input[@type='text']")
  List<WebElement> dataSourceName;
  ```
- **Note**: If your *usecase* is to *find an element*, you won't need a `List` but a **`WebElement`**